# Java: Processing Stream line by line without forEach?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java and trying out Streams for the first time.

I have a large input file where there is a string on each line like:

```
cart
dumpster
apple
cherry
tank
laptop
...
```

I'm trying to read the file in as a Stream and doing some analysis on the data. For example, to count all the occurrences of a particular string, I might think to do something like:

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Path.of("/path/to/input/file.txt"));
int count = 0;

lines.forEach((line) => {
    if (line.equals("tank")) {
        count++;
    }
});
```

But, Java doesn't allow mutation of variables within the lambda.

I'm not sure if there's another way to read from the stream line by line. How would I do this properly?

Comment: Not an answer but take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) to learn about comparing strings.

Comment: In general, instead of just using Stream for simple iteration, make use of its method as `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, `collect`, `reduce`. They are super powerful. `forEach` ideally should be used only if you want to execute some action on each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To iterate a stream using a regular loop, you can get an iterator from your stream and use a for-loop:

```
Iterable<String> iterable = lines::iterator;
for (String line : iterable) {
    if (line.equals("tank")) {
         ++count;
    }
}
```

But in this particular case, you could just use the stream's [count](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) method:

```
int count = (int) lines.filter("tank"::equals).count();
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer actually helped me solve my real issue which wasn't just about counting occurrences but showing me how to iterate over the stream without using a lambda in`forEach`

Comment: Well, if you don’t use the benefits of the Stream API, don’t use a Stream in the first place. To iterate over the lines of a file, you can use a `BufferedReader` or a `Scanner`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a variable external to the stream. And if you have a really big file to count, `long` would be preferred

```
long tanks = lines
    .filter(s -> s.equals("tank"))
    .count();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read from the file line by line, with stream of each one :

```
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Path.of("/path/to/input/file.txt"))) {
        list = stream
                .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("abc"))
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```